# Realigning Fish Distribution to NHD Stream Layer

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, line, arcgis-10.7

I'm working to realign Fish Habitat Distribution line layers to my NHD Flowline layer in ArcMap. Both layers are in the same projection and there is only a slight difference between the two. I've been working on a model to realign the fish distribution layer since I am analyzing a large area and would rather not do the advanced edits by hand.

[image: Fish Distribution in Red and NHD Stream in Blue]

My first approach used snapping, which got me really close to a good end product, but there are still errors. I then went back and added more vertices to my stream layer to improve snapping. Once again, close but no cigar. I see there is an align features tool in the editing toolbox, but it crashes at the last step each time that I use it.
[image: Model Builder approach to snapping fish distribution to stream layer]

For some background, I want to intersect the fish distribution layer on top of the stream layer in order to classify the stream based off an ESA Biological Opinion (ex. A Perennial stream with an ESA listed species is Class 1). A Spatial join is too conservative for this analysis because an entire reach will assume the characteristics of the fish distribution, even if the fish travel halfway up through the reach. Therefore, I want to use the fish distribution as a cookie cutter to splice the streams in order to have a more accurate symbology and analysis.

Ideally, I'd love to find a tool that functions like a spatial join, but has the accuracy and results of the intersect tool.

Comment: Do you have cases when second line starts above stream junction and ends below junction on next reach downstream? Or it's always simple case as shown?

Comment: @FelixIP, Sometimes that is the case, yes.

Comment: Have a look at RivEX it has a [create reach tool](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Creatingreaches.html), you could take the top end of your existing reaches, and generate a down stream reach for a predefined length.  Alternatively if your network is a measured network you could look into linear referencing for defining reaches along your river network?

Answer (score 0):

No surprise in your answer to my Q in comment. 'Fish' people (ecologists?) don't understand river networks. It makes your task more difficult. So split 'fish' lines by points at the stream junctions. To obtain junctions use Feature vertices to points twice: first - compute both ends, second dangles. Delete points from first set that intersect dangles and delete identical using Shape field.

Compute mid points of fish lines and run Near tool between them and streams. Transfer NEAR_FID values to fish lines. It gives your enough info to cut streams into segments and use them to amend fish lines accordingly.

So rename sream lines layer to "streams" in your mxd and run this code in field calculator on field Shape of backup(!) copy of fish lines:

```py
aDict ={}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("streams",("OID@","Shape@")) as cursor:
 for fid,shpR in cursor:aDict[fid]=shpR

def sliceStreams( shp, nfid):
 stream = aDict[nfid]
 ps = shp.firstPoint; f = stream.measureOnLine(ps)
 ps = shp.lastPoint; t = stream.measureOnLine(ps)
 segment = stream.segmentAlongLine(f,t)
 return segment
```

---

```py
sliceStreams( !Shape!, !NEAR_FID!)
```